# static Vs non static methods & members interaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables, static-methods, webmethod

i have a `WebMethod`  that serves an Ajax AutoComplete Extender as it's DataSource.

`FontnmsList_AutCpltDataSrc()`

so it must be `static` ,... unless I will implement it through another approach... such as `Web Service`,  as i wouldn't like to use, and actually, that's not the issue here anyways.

so ... being a **static method**, and a it needs to co-work with rest of data of current application ...that is **not static**....there's a little problem here ..

now as i have been advised to **refrain from using static** in general (was referring `asp.net`),  and while trying to follow that advice,

i could see that in order to allow interaction with it... the web method is kind of leading me to convert all of my other  application elements / data types and methods to use a `static` modifier, for instance ,

this is an example I came across with current project.

```C#
// non static 
public SeSn.CurrentSesionVariablsTmplt ExtractSesnVar()
{
    SeSn.CurrentSesionVariablsTmplt RetrndAppGlobals = SeSn.GetValueAS.ACloneOfGlobalsObj("_CurrentSesionGlobals");
    return (SeSn.CurrentSesionVariablsTmplt)RetrndAppGlobals ;

}
```

now this is the web method that is responsible for autocomplete extender

```C#
public static List<string> FntsList = new List<string>();


[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

public static List<string> FontnmsList_AutCpltDataSrc(string prefixText)
{ 

    if (ExtrctSesnVar().Fntlist != null)
    { 
        //here too , non of these are , except for the List of course
        FntsList = RflectMeths.ClassFldsAsList<fntNams>();
        CurrSesnDatabag.Fntlist = FntsList;
        SeSn.Modify(Act.Add, App.VarNms._CurrentSesionGlobals, CurrSesnDatabag);
    }
    else
        FntsList = ExtractSesnVar().Fntlist;

    return AutoComplete.FromListStr(prefixText, FntsList);
}
```

so a non-static `ExtractSesnVar()` is required for work within

a `static` web method `FontnmsList_AutCpltDataSrc()` scope.

so it makes me wonder ...
What basic knowledge am I lacking here (:
I mean,  did you ever get in to this junction when you started learning .net ?

and as for what is called in SO A Real Question :

what is the work around as a solution to this scenario,(its only one example . as there should be many other 'junctions'  like this one, that you could come up with)

I should think there's supposed to be some way,  to `bridge` between these two entities while writing I could think of passing in data which is non static as parameter ,

**so what am i missing here . what is the correct solution as for the subjetced code above ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking: How can I call instance methods from a static method?

There are only 3 options:

1. You could create a single static instance of the object that has the methods required. This will only work if this instance can be reset or doesn't hold any state.
2. You create a new instance on every single call and use it.
3. Make everything static. (not recommended)

Sometimes, instance methods only require 1 or perhaps 2 pieces of state information from the instance and in those cases it's easier to turn them into static and have the instance method call the static method with the extra bit of state information. Check if this is the case here.

for example, imagine you have a very simple class like this:

```
public class something
{
  public int One { get;set; }
  public int Two { get;set; }

  public int Add()
  {
    return One + Two;
  }
}
```

and you had a static method that needed to call Add, you could refactor the above code into below code so that you didn't have to create an instance anymore in your static method, but still had the Add logic in one place:

```
public class something
{
  public int One { get;set; }
  public int Two { get;set; }

  public int Add()
  {
    return Add(One, Two);
  }

  internal static int Add(int one, int two) 
  {
    return one + two;
  }
}
```

I've chosen to make the static Add method internal so only other classes in your assembly and friend assemblies can call it. Feel free to make it public if it makes sense in your scenario.

None of this is ideal, but it might be worthwhile in your case. YMMV.

Comment: could you be more informative like a code sample for instance , hard to know what you are talking about(for as much as my knowledge gets) like by saying " *require 1 or perhaps 2 pieces of state information*" (by the way i did get to be noted about this in my last question by @millimoose i will take care of it )

Comment: Andy , thanks ,though only one comment... when you put the additional converted class you could then say "Enter The `Internal`... modifier" or something like this (P , as I understand it should serve the static members within the application ...

Comment: noticed that i hadn't made my extra Add method static! code updated

Comment: ..no , i didn't notice another TRICK , i was thinking about it my self while writing the question but first wanted to see what expereienced developers are doing, see just at the end of my post passed as parameter part

Comment: ok so two versions, one static one not . just refreshed browser

Comment: and you manged to make diferences by over ride the parameterless add with the one that needs a parameter so "no one", will be able to use static `Add()` unless that is what it Intended to ...that is what it was after..